# Unable to use a DirectX function?

Tags: c++, directx-11, lnk2019

I get the `LNK2019` error when I try to use `D3DX11CompileFromFile` function in my C++ project. The error reads:

> Error  1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _D3DX11CompileFromFileW@44 referenced in function "void __cdecl InitPipeline(void)" (?InitPipeline@@YAXXZ)    C:\Users\Username\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Window0\Window0\Window0.obj Window0'

I also can't open `d3dx11.lib` and 10 even after changing the address and dependency settings for what it's worth. I have tried moving the files around and changing user rights but I still can't get the sweet thing to work.

Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The D3DX library has been deprecated in DirectX 11.  Unless you absolutely need it, you should instead use [D3DCompileFromFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446872(v=vs.85).aspx) or compile the shaders offline with the **fxc.exe** shader compiler.

If you do need the D3DX library, you'll need to install the June 2010 DirectX SDK and update your Visual Studio paths. See this article: [Where is the DirectX SDK?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: There is now a new option: You can use the [Microsoft.DXSDK.D3DX](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.DXSDK.D3DX) NuGet package instead of the legacy DirectX SDK. That said, D3DX11 is still deprecated so you should still look at the various [replacements](https://walbourn.github.io/living-without-d3dx/).